# Setting max_depth greater than the number of features in a Random Forest

Tags: regression, machine-learning, random-forest

I was using random forest regression to predict the price of a house. There are only 3 features in data set. Initially when I had set `max_depth=2` the result was highly biased. The performance improved with `max_depth=8`, but my question is how can we set `max_depth` greater than the total number of features.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question quite heavily, since I believe the question you asked in your first paragraph is quite useful - whereas the second paragraph was unclear (what is $n$?). It would be a pity if a useful question was closed as "unclear" because of an unclear second paragraph. I'd encourage you to put up a second post to ask the question in your second paragraph (but please make it a bit clearer). Feel free to include links between your two posts. Of course, if you disagree with my edit, please feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no problem with setting the maximum depth of a Random Forest (or more specifically, of any tree) higher than the number of features.

For instance, you could have two features, `Age` and `Sex`. Then you could have a series of splits that first check whether `Age>18`, if so check whether `Sex=M`, if so check whether `Age>40`. The end result would be four leaves/bins, one for `Age<=18`, one for `Age>18 & Sex=F`, one for `18<Age<=40 & Sex=M` and one for `Age>40 & Sex=M`.

Comment: so you mean the same feature can be present at multiple levels but maybe with different conditions.  I earlier used to think each feature can be only present once in a  particular flow. Thanks for the help Stephan.

Answer (score 0):

A tree's(Decision Tree/ RF) nodes are only split based on the Information Gain or Gini impurity. The number of features is not a parameter(more precisely, hyperparameter).